# stepsize x-axe with time string labels

Tags: chart.js

this is my code part, which I am using at the moment for chart.js

```js
var lineChartData = {
  labels: ['08:00', '08:05', '08:10', '08:15', '08:20', '08:25', '08:30', '08:35', '08:40', '08:45', '08:50', '08:55', '09:00'],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Temperatur (°C)',
    borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
    backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
    fill: false,
    data: [23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23],
    yAxisID: 'y-axis-1',
    cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone'
  }, {
    label: 'Feuchtigkeit (%)',
    borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
    backgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,
    fill: false,
    data: [34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34],
    yAxisID: 'y-axis-2',
    cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone'
  }]
};

window.onload = function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  window.myLine = Chart.Line(ctx, {
    data: lineChartData,
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      hoverMode: 'index',
      stacked: false,
      scales: {

        xAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            minRotation: 0,
            maxRotation: 90
          }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            type: 'linear',
            display: true,
            position: 'left',
            id: 'y-axis-1',
            ticks: {
              max: 60,
              min: 0,
              stepSize: 10
            }
          },
          {
            type: 'linear',
            display: true,
            position: 'right',
            id: 'y-axis-2',
            ticks: {
              max: 60,
              min: 0,
              stepSize: 10
            }
          }
        ],
      }
    }
  });
};
```

I have time string labels with 5 minutes between each other on my x-axe
I added this parameter to my "xAxes Part"

```
xAxes: [{
   ticks: {
      minRotation: 0,
      maxRotation: 90
   },
   type: 'time',
   time: {
      unit: 'hour'
   }
}]
```

Now my chart doesn't work anymore. Only a white page.
I think the problem is, that my x-axe only shows string time labels, but as a string, not as a time value. Can this be the problem?

If yes, how can I solve this?
Is there an exmaple for that?

Thanks a lot !! :)

** UPDATE **

there is one little thing before I can say: "It is perfect ! :)

[image]
1. How can I format the tooltip information? It should be: 28.04.2020 - 05:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your labels are not in RFC2822 or ISO format and cannot be parsed to a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object. You need to define the format to be used for parsing your time strings. Chart.js internally uses Moment.js to parse the dates. Therefore you should refer to [Moment.js documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to find out about valid formats.

```
xAxes: [{
  ...
  type: 'time',
  time: {
    parser: 'HH:mm',
    unit: 'hour'
  }
```

> Make sure also to use the [bundled version](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html#bundled-build) of Chart.js that includes Moment.js in a single file.

Please have a look at your amended code below.

```js
var lineChartData = {
  labels: ['08:00', '08:05', '08:10', '08:15', '08:20', '08:25', '08:30', '08:35', '08:40', '08:45', '08:50', '08:55', '09:00'],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Temperatur (°C)',
    borderColor: 'red',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    fill: false,
    data: [23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23],
    yAxisID: 'y-axis-1',
    cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone'
  }, {
    label: 'Feuchtigkeit (%)',
    borderColor: 'blue',
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    fill: false,
    data: [34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34],
    yAxisID: 'y-axis-2',
    cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone'
  }]
};

window.onload = function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  window.myLine = Chart.Line(ctx, {
    data: lineChartData,
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      hoverMode: 'index',
      stacked: false,
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            minRotation: 0,
            maxRotation: 90
          },
          type: 'time',
          time: {
            parser: 'HH:mm',
            unit: 'hour',
            displayFormats: {
              hour: 'HH:mm'
            }
          }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            type: 'linear',
            display: true,
            position: 'left',
            id: 'y-axis-1',
            ticks: {
              max: 60,
              min: 0,
              stepSize: 10
            }
          },
          {
            type: 'linear',
            display: true,
            position: 'right',
            id: 'y-axis-2',
            ticks: {
              max: 60,
              min: 0,
              stepSize: 10
            }
          }
        ],
      }
    }
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! But 8AM and 9AM should be 08:00 and 09:00 (24 format). How can I change this?

Comment: @Ghost108: You can change the format by defining `time.displayFormats`. I just updated the code snippet in my answer accordingly.

Comment: you made my day!! Thanks a lot !! :) There are two little things. Can you please check my "Update Part" of post 1? thanks !!

Comment: Please post new questions for this new issues. It makes it easier to provide accurate and cocise answers for each of them.

Comment: done :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61474243/change-date-format-in-tooltip-of-chart-js

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the `chartColors` object, so assuming those colors and added them by default. Also, I am expecting that you have installed `moment.js` library before `chart.js` library for **Time** type charts to work.

Other than that, the `labels` you're providing are not in the standard Date format, (e.g. 2020-05-29T08:02:00Z) and you need to pass `time.parser` option to define that you're specifying only `hours` of the date. Read more about [parser](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#parser)

```js
window.chartColors = {
'red': '#ff0000',
'blue': '#0000ff'
}
var lineChartData = {
  labels: ['08:00:00', '08:05:00', '08:10:00', '08:15:00', '08:20', '08:25', '08:30', '08:35', '08:40', '08:45', '08:50', '08:55', '09:00'],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Temperatur (°C)',
    borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
    backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
    fill: false,
    data: [23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23],
    yAxisID: 'y-axis-1',
    cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone'
  }, {
    label: 'Feuchtigkeit (%)',
    borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
    backgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,
    fill: false,
    data: [34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34],
    yAxisID: 'y-axis-2',
    cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone'
  }]
};

function init() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  window.myLine = Chart.Line(ctx, {
    data: lineChartData,
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      hoverMode: 'index',
      stacked: false,
      scales: {

        xAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            minRotation: 0,
            maxRotation: 90
          },
          type: 'time',
          time: {
            unit: 'hour',
            parser: 'hh'
          }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            type: 'linear',
            display: true,
            position: 'left',
            id: 'y-axis-1',
            ticks: {
              max: 60,
              min: 0,
              stepSize: 10
            }
          },
          {
            type: 'linear',
            display: true,
            position: 'right',
            id: 'y-axis-2',
            ticks: {
              max: 60,
              min: 0,
              stepSize: 10
            }
          }
        ],
      }
    }
  });
};
window.onload = init();
```

Working demo, [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uLf6hgnx/2/)