# change date format in tooltip of chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I am using the chart.js to generate a chart.
All works fine !

[image]

But how can I format the tooltip information? It should be: 28.04.2020 - 05:00

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define [`time.tooltipFormat`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#display-formats) for your `xAxis`.

> See [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) for the allowed format tokens.

```
options: {
    ...
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
            time: {
                unit: 'hour',
                tooltipFormat: 'DD.MM.YYYY - HH:mm' 
            }
            ...
        }]
    }
    ... 
}
```

Comment: See https://date-fns.org/v3.3.1/docs/format for the allowed date-fns tokens.